# p:datalist varStatus.last always false

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to add a separator **between** every entry in the collection in a p:datalist (PF 3.4), as follows:

```
<p:dataList id="feed" value="#{allProfessorsMB.selectedProfessor.courseList}" var="course" varStatus="status">                           
    <p:outputLabel value="#{course.name}"/>
    <p:separator id="separator" rendered="#{!status.last}"/>                           
</p:dataList>
```

It seams that #{!status.last} always returns true, since the separator is always rendered.
I tried it with some text (instead of the separator line) like this #{status.last ? 'true' : 'false'} and it prints 'false' all the time.

I have seen a lot of examples of JSTL tags and some of ui:repeat, but not similar to this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like:

```
<p:dataList rowIndexVar="rowIndex" rowCountVar="rowCount" id="feed" value="#{allProfessorsMB.selectedProfessor.courseList}" var="course">
    <p:outputLabel value="#{course.name}"/>
    <p:separator id="separator" rendered="#{rowIndex + 1 != rowCount}"/>
</p:dataList>
```